# Node.js - Getting return value from MySQL before proceeding

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am currently using node.js to communicate with my database. I'm having an issue where i want to wait for async database query before it continues.

I've tried many example from the internet and i can't seem to find the way to do it or the problem of it. What happened is that after the mysql query, it will proceed to the next line without waiting for the return value.

Here is my code:

```js
//Connection with database
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "justcall"
});
console.log("before insert");

function queryPromise(str){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(str, (err, result, fields) => {
      if(err) reject(err);
      resolve(result);
    })
  })
}

async function run(){
  let answer = await queryPromise("INSERT INTO calllog (userId, callId, timeCalled, callDuration, status, callType) VALUES ('27', '33', '2019-11-13 22:30:20', '00:00:01', '1', '1')");
  console.log(answer);
}

run();

console.log("after insert");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `run()` is asynchronous, you need to wait for it.

```
run().then(function() { console.log("after insert"); });
```

If you call it from another async function, you can use `await`:

```
async function doit() {
    await run();
    console.log("after insert");
}
doit();
```

Comment: thank you! it is a bit different from what i imagine how it should be but this is fine as long as i can do it.